# MATLAB's rand(,'double'), trouble summing to the average

Tags: matlab, random

I'm finding that MATLAB's random number generator appears to only be accurate to single precision, even when 'double' is used for a return type.

The simple test I am using is

> mean((rand(1,100000000,'double')))

which gets the same result I found by doing a running average on rand().  The mean stops converging at single precision.

Am I missing something?

Edit:

A quick running average to sum a very large number of samples:

```
% use vpa to reduce round off
runningMean = vpa(0);
samples = vpa(0);

% grab groups (significantly faster)
groupSize = 5000000;
while(true)
    runningMean = (runningMean*samples+groupSize*mean(rand(1,1,groupSize)));
    samples = samples + groupSize;
    runningMean = runningMean / samples;

    fprintf('\nN: %d \tmean: %.15f', double(samples), double(runningMean));
end
```

Edit:

A plot of the error versus samples

[image: error vs samples]

Comment: Just checking, but you are aware that `mean((rand(1,100000000)))` is actually double precision right? i.e. double is the default type in Matlab

Comment: Yes, just being doubly sure by passing double since I was finding errors at single precision :)

Comment: What do you mean it stop convergin to single precision? the mean of rand(1,100000000) is 0.5, spetially using that huge amount of data. What do you expect?

Comment: Additionally, you may want to set up the 'format long' so you can see all the decimals of your result, not only the first 4 ones

Comment: @Ander Biguri, I get values such as 0.500004987522602, where I would expect to be able to drive it closer to 0.5 with increased sample sizes.

Comment: With 1e8 samples you should get an RMS error for the mean of the order of 3e-5 (.3/sqrt(1e8)). So your observed error seems perfectly reasonable (even too low). To drive the error down to single precision levels you would need about 1e14 samples (`eps('single')` gives about 1e-7)

Comment: Yes, "closer" but well, not exactly. Welcome to computer generated random numbers. There is people working, doing PhD,... just to improve random number generation.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I don't think this is a matter of random number generation. Even with perfectly well-generated random numbers, with 1e8 sampls I'd expect a (random) error even larger than indicated by the OP (seem y comment above)

Comment: @Luis Mendo, agreed, but the issue I'm finding is I hit a 'wall' right around single precision when I go larger.  I'll put the code up and someone can hopefully point out my oversight :)

Comment: @ccook That's interesting. Could you also include the graph of how that error hits a wall?

Comment: @LuisMendo Agreed. I didn't make my point clear enough. You are completely right there.

Comment: @Luis Mendo, added the plot

Comment: @ccook At which `N` (approximately) do you start to see the error hits a wall?

Comment: Seems to be between 1E7 and 1E8

Comment: @ccook: that's not the best way to measure precision of RAND, you're ignoring the fact that SUM and MEAN introduce round-off error themselves. Just compare: `x=rand(1e7,1); sum(x) - sum(sort(x))`

Comment: @Amro,  you are right, the round off errors are adding up from the bottom and meeting in the 'middle'.  I wasn't trying to test RAND as much as figure out why I couldnt drive the error lower.

Comment: @Amro That's true, but those errors are probably so small that it would take much more than 1e8 samples to notice them

Comment: @Amro, just used a compensated summation to address that issue and still find the issue- ill update the plot though

Comment: @Amro, there is a nice compensated summation (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26800-xsum/content/XSum.m)  which does well with the simple test you gave.  I still hit that issue using it for all of the summations though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run a slightly modified verson of your code that collects all partial results and plots them. Superimposed is the theoretical RMS error:

```
% use vpa to reduce round off
runningMean = vpa(0);
samples = vpa(0);

% grab groups (significantly faster)
groupSize = 5000000;
K = 1000;
results = NaN(1,K); %// initiallize
for k = 1:K
    runningMean = (runningMean*samples+groupSize*mean(rand(1,1,groupSize)));
    samples = samples + groupSize;
    runningMean = runningMean / samples;
    fprintf('\nIteration: %d \tN: %d \tmean: %.15f',...
        k, double(samples), double(runningMean));
    results(k) = runningMean;
end

%// plot    
loglog((1:k)*groupSize, abs(results-.5))
hold on
loglog(groupSize*[1 k], 1/sqrt(12)./sqrt(groupSize*[1 k]), 'g--') %// theoretical
```

As you see, the obtained values (blue) seem to follow the expected trend given by the theoretical RMS error (green). Of course, the comparison is far from perfect because I'm comparing a *sample value* of the error (a single value, for each `N`) with an *RMS* error. To do it right you'd have to run the experiment say 1e4 times; for each `N` compute the RMS value of those 1e4 errors; and that *should* agree more with the theoretical RMS value. Still, the trend can be appreciated even with a single run.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Luis Mendo, the thing that was bugging was that the convergence stopped at a point, rather than it was slow - very nice theoretical comparison though.  The matching is very good with a compensated summation (which lets convergence continue).

Comment: I don't get it... How/why did convergence "stop"? It doesn't in my code, which is essentially yours plus the plotting

Comment: The summation would be dominated by the round off errors from the billions of summations - I get your plot to a point, where round off errors bubble up and dominate.  Using the compensated summation helps keep them down, though. (Nice plot by the way :) )

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simplified implementation of the same thing:

```
sz = 5e6;               % batch size
num = 1000;             % number of batches
s = zeros(1,num);       % sum in each batch
for i=1:num
    s(i) = sum(rand(sz,1));
end
csz = sz .* (1:num);    % cumulative sizes
cs = cumsum(s) ./ csz;  % cumulative means
```

Now we plot the results along with the theoretical error @LuisMendo discussed. Again we see the empirical error curve following the theoretical trend line:

```
subplot(121), semilogx(csz, cs)
line(csz([1 end]), [0.5 0.5], 'Color','m', 'LineStyle',':')
title('x = rand(N,1)'), xlabel('N'), ylabel('mean(x)')
axis tight

subplot(122), loglog(csz, abs(cs-0.5))
line(csz([1 end]), 1./sqrt(csz([1 end])*12), 'Color','m', 'LineStyle',':')
title('x = rand(N,1)'), xlabel('N'), ylabel('|mean(x)-0.5|')
axis tight
```

[image: screenshot]

---

You could also try the code with a better [summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) (see [`XSum`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26800-xsum) on FEX). Simply replace `sum` in the loop with `XSum`, and the final `cumsum` with:

```
cs = arrayfun(@(i) XSum(s(1:i)), 1:numel(s)) ./ csz;
```